# Password Resetting in Java

Tags: java, passwords, recovery

Could anyone please provide resources on how to reset password in Java web application connected to db where password stored as hashed(password+salt+secretphrase)? I am also using Spring, so if it has something in this area please identify.

I know the general technique:

1. "Password reset" button
2. Ask user to confirm its identity - via entering email.
3. Token is generated and send to mail adress. (how ? It is hash of what? which properties? how to send automatic mail message?-never done that before)
4. User goes to token link provided webpage, where new password field awaiting.

   - Token has time validity, judging from other similar questions ideally few hours.
   - Don't use security questions as they infinitely impractical.

What I am asking is some pseudo-code or example implementation on how to generate tokens and send token mails to users.

Comment: What type of password recovery are we talking about here? Password cracking? Resetting a hash in a database? Emailing a user a new auto-generated password?

Comment: And I still have no clue why you down vote my question. I've clarified as much as possible...

Comment: In a basic sense this isn't too different than a 'standard' webform - the button updates the password stored in the database (and expires it), then forwards it to the (_stored_) email address.  The tricky part is managing access around this, to decrease the likelyhood that the functionality is being used to fraudulently gaining access to the user's account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say java, do you mean web application in java ?
Your functionality needs a lot of different components.

- For the password recovery, add a button in jsp which makes a call to servlet. That servlet should redirect to a new jsp which has field to enter email.
- Once the enter the email and submits. The request should go to another servlet which makes a db call and verifies the email. If the email is valid, then you can generate a token. Token can be generated by the Math.random() function. Generate some bunch of numbers and using those numbers create a string. e.g. for creating an all alphabet string divide the number by 26 and choose the character based on the remainder.
- Finally another jsp page which allows choosing a new password.

You can use JavaMail api for sending emails.
Spring framework has many components, you can use it for frontend, DB calls and for sending mail. You need to go through the documentation to learn about them.

Comment: Why not hash something like user_id +user_name+mail to create token?

Comment: Thats another way of doing it.